# No space left on device (28)

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to use `rsync` to transfer nearly 4GB of files onto a remote server that is supposed to be 20GB big.

On my computer, I run `rsync -av --ignore-existing --inplace my_directory --compress-level=9 root@REMOTE.IP.ADDRESS:~/`

The terminal prints a bunch of files being copies successfully for a while, then it prints this error.

`rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/path/to/some/directory" failed: No space left on device (28)`

I `ssh` into my remote server. I run `df -h`. I see this (removed unneeded text).

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20G  5.8G   13G  32% /
devtmpfs        488M  4.0K  488M   1% /dev
```

I clearly have space on my remote server. Also, when I `ssh` into my remote server and run `touch test`, A file names `test` is created. But when I run `touch test2` after that, I get this error: `touch: cannot touch ‘test2’: No space left on device`.

How do I transfer the rest of my folders and files to a remote server that claims it has no more space despite having space?

**Update**

Running `df -i` shows this.

```
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/root      1213440 1213440      0  100% /
```

Comment: no inodes available anymore? run `df -i`.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Updated question